# Access the Stage in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, stage

I'm trying to get a projector file to run full screen when it starts, without needing to click anything.  My main class inherits from MovieClip, so as far as I can tell I get access to stage... yeah right :)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;


    public class PhoneDemo extends MovieClip
    {
        Stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        //declare variables
        public var scoreArray:Array = [null];
```

This simply doesn't work, I can't gain access to stage, I get error 1120.  I'm sure I've gained access to the stage before, I'm really confused.

Answer (score 4):

`stage` is a property of DisplayObject; `Stage` is the class.

Try accessing it in lowercase instead. Also, if you access the stage in the constructor it won't have been assigned yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class PhoneDemo extends MovieClip{
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
   // you cannot access the stage here, because the stage relation has not been established
}

internal function addedToStage(e:Event){
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
    // you  can access the stage here
}
```